# Not able to edit text inline in button tags

Tags: jss

I am using Sitecore 9.3 with JSS.

I have created few components that have buttons. The button labels are editable in sitecore.

The issue is when I edit those button labels inline, e.g, I need to add text - 'Sign In' as button label, then after 'Sign' when I enter space and write 'In', it does not show up. When I check via Inspect Element, it shows that it has added '&nbsp' tags.

This is only happening with text inside 'button' tags and only with inline editing in Experience Editor.

**Screenshot -**

[image]
**Code -**
/src/components/componentName/index.js

```
<Button variant="primary" type="submit">
<Text field={props.fields.buttonlabel} />
</Button>
```

Can anybody please suggest a resolution for this?

Comment: I think you have to handle this via CSS and when you hit enter it's ignoring the text because of single line of text https://react-jss-typescript-starter-develop.azurewebsites.net/styleguide. If you will check the sample app > style guide then you will get information about multiline text field

Comment: @AmitKumar can you plese elaborate more?